# What is the English equivalent of an 意匠ノート?

Tags: words

I came across the term 「意匠ノート」as a type of notebook. Translated, I guess it would be a "design notebook," but I'm not sure what that means? A drawing book? A notebook with graph paper for architectural designing? If anyone has any insight,  would appreciate it!

Comment: I get the feeling it may mean something more like cute / stylish / chic / *designer* notebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「意匠ノート」 doesn't means 'notebook for designer'.

「意匠ノート」means ...
Notebook that have not only notebook feature, but also good looking (or / and) more useful design.

---

For Example

This notebook cut obliquely to turn the pages easily.
( for more useful design )
http://www.kokuyo-st.co.jp/stationery/campus_p/design/

This is a notebook with lacework.
( for good looking design )
http://www.kokuyo-st.co.jp/stationery/gracieux/note.html#01

Japanese stationery maker KOKUYO uses the word "意匠ノート" well.
Those are slightly useful or slightly beautiful.
(in Japanese ちょっと便利 or ちょっとかわいい ).

Comment: I agree, yet ironically most of the google image results for 意匠ノート are very... plain https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=%E6%84%8F%E5%8C%A0%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dGI&biw=1920&bih=912&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Y-PXUZkCx9WQBYiKgdAK

Comment: > ssb : I understand. FYI, I wrote some example.

Comment: > yobisute : you are welcome!  どういたしまして(^-^)

Comment: @fliedonion use the @ mark to message people directly!